# Rails: All examples were filtered out - 0 examples, 0 failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm working on Chapter 9 of Hartl's rails tutorial.  I just added some tests to test the 'edit' page, which allows users to edit their profile info.

When I ran  'bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"' I got "All examples were filtered out ... 0 examples, 0 failures".  Does that mean nothing got tested? If so, how can I fix this?

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit
page'
Run options: include {:full_description=>/edit\ page'/}

All examples were filtered out


Finished in 0 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means nothing was tested.  The problem is

```
-e "edit page'
```

is closed with the wrong type of quote.  Use either single or double quotes to enclose the string:

```
-e "edit page"
```

Comment: For people coming from Google... this error can also be caused by other things, like accidentally putting your `it` block specs inside a `let` statement, or anything that causes there to simply not be any specs. But if you're pretty sure there should be, then it's probably a little syntax error like that somewhere.

Comment: Correct @bwest87. Also, another reason can be that you've set a tag in your rspec command, like `--tag focus`, but don't have any specs focussed with that tag. Generally in this case you want *all* specs to run, but this is not the default. Add this config in `spec/spec_helper.rb` to make it so: `config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true`